# Is there a way to get subversion to add files to a default changelist?

Tags: svn, changelist

I'd like to be able to tell svn to automatically add new files to a default changelist, mostly as a workaround to svn's lack of a "no changelist" filter. Is there an official way of doing this? I can write a little script to do it, but if there's a way to do it that will integrate well with the command-line client, I'd love to know about it.

If svn used properties to mark files as members of a changelist, this would be dead simple (I think). Alas, this is not the case.

I'm using 1.6.9

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here?

Comment: I make fairly heavy use of changelists, sometimes having a few atomic types of things that have been worked on before a commit is ready for any of them. Sometimes I'll have a few changelists, and want to operate on some files that aren't a member of any of them. Sometimes I'll have one changelist that isn't ready to commit, and some other files that are that aren't in a changelist. There's a few other use cases. Since svn doesn't have a `--changelist ''`  yet, having files be in a changelist by default would make some filtering tasks a tad quicker and cleaner to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As svn dosnt support changesets/lists on finer granularity than the single commit I'd doubt there is any officaly "good" way to implement it.
You could attempt to do it yourself by introducing some properties ...

key: myprops:changelist
value: refactoringwork 20:41,150:153,337:360
       jiratask1234 409:445

You would have to manage it all from the IDE-Level to the serverqueries if you want to only get certain changelists for example.

I would not attempt to do it.